# Why sublist access time increases with sublist size?

Tags: python, list, performance, indexing

The code below initializes a list of random integers, and iterates over it. Given a `subset_size`, at every iteration `i`, a sublist of `i: i + subset_size` is accessed. The time to access the sublist grows with `subset_size`. For `n = 100000` and `subset_size = 50000`, it takes 15+ seconds on my i5 mbp. I thought sublists are retrieved using 2 pointers and lazy evaluation but it looks like there's some `c` loop behind the scenes that populates a new list and returns it as a result. Is this a proper description to what actually happens or is there another explanation?

```
import random
from datetime import timedelta
from time import perf_counter


def example(n, subset_size):
    x = [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(n)]
    t = perf_counter()
    for i in range(n - subset_size):
        _ = x[i : i + subset_size]
    print(timedelta(seconds=perf_counter() - t))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example(100000, 50000)
```

---

```
0:00:15.131059
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the number of iterations of your for loop depends on the value of `subset_size`. If `subset_size == n` you iterate 0 times but if `subset_size == 0` you loop n times. You are measuring the time the for loop takes to complete, so iterating a different number of times for sure will affect how long it takes to complete

Comment: That's not the problem, in fact, the total iterations is `n - subset_size` which means  the total iterations (50000 in this case) decreases as `subset_size` grows.

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure I get what you mean. if `subset_size` grows the number of iterations will no longer be the same. in your example it's 100.000-50.000 = 50.000 iterations, now if you grow `subset_size` to say 80.000 you will end with 100.000-80.000 = 20.000 iterations. So if you compare how long 50.000 iteratins take vs 20.000 iterations you will for sure see a significant difference in time

Comment: I agree with what you said but it sounds like you're arguing that the number of iterations grows with `subset_size` which may have explained the increase in duration. I'm clarifying it's just the opposite, so technically, less total time should be needed because, less number of iterations.

Comment: Ok, we agree. So you will observe different times for different values of `subset_size`. Then what is your question exactly? Sorry I don't get what you are asking. You are measuring the time a loop takes to complete, and this loop depends on a variable.

Comment: The question is what is happening behind the scenes causing the delay or in other words, why a `subset_size` of `100` requires 100x the time a `subset_size` of 1 would require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought sublists are retrieved using 2 pointers and lazy evaluation
> but it looks like there's some c loop behind the scenes that populates
> a new list and returns it as a result.

Your assumption is correct. slicing a list always creates new list. Here is the [relevant part of the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L468-L491). I have added some comments to understand what is being going on each steps.

```
static PyObject *
list_slice(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t ilow, Py_ssize_t ihigh)
{
    PyListObject *np;
    PyObject **src, **dest;
    Py_ssize_t i, len;
    len = ihigh - ilow;
    if (len <= 0) {
        return PyList_New(0);
    }
    # create new list which is long enough to hold the slice length elements.
    np = (PyListObject *) list_new_prealloc(len);
    if (np == NULL)
        return NULL;
    # Adjust the pointer offset, because list internally uses an array of pointers.
    src = a->ob_item + ilow;
    dest = np->ob_item;
    # Copy the elements back.
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        PyObject *v = src[i];
        Py_INCREF(v);
        dest[i] = v;
    }
    Py_SET_SIZE(np, len);
    return (PyObject *)np;
}
```

As you can see when you slice a list it has to first call [`list_new_prealloc` which](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L201-L215) is where an empty list is created and allocates the memory upto the slice length.

```
static PyObject *
list_new_prealloc(Py_ssize_t size)
{
    assert(size > 0);
    # Create new list
    PyListObject *op = (PyListObject *) PyList_New(0);
    if (op == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    assert(op->ob_item == NULL);
    # Allocating memory
    op->ob_item = PyMem_New(PyObject *, size);
    if (op->ob_item == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(op);
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    }
    op->allocated = size;
    return (PyObject *) op;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List slicing is not evaluated lazily, and indeed creates a new list object; see for example [An Informal Introduction to Python, section 3.1.3. Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements.

Answer (score -1):

List slice would not be evaluated lazily, the list will be created on every iteration. Use `itertools.islice` to create lazy slice:
`islice(x, i, i + subset_size)`

Comment: `itertools.islice` works with iterators, not sequences. It won't perform efficient lazy index arithmetic to handle the slice; it will treat `x` as a general iterable, retrieve an iterator, and *iterate* through elements one by one until it hits index `i`, then start yielding elements from there. This is extremely inefficient.

Comment: I have benchmarked, it works as expected, lazily. Iterator is not iterating elements on creation

Comment: It won't iterate on *creation*, but as soon as you try to retrieve even a single element, it's going to iterate. (Sure, the code in the question doesn't try to do that, but if all you wanted was an implementation that works as long as you don't try to do anything with it, you could just use `None` and pretend that was your slice.)

Comment: Question was asking about lazy creation and provided sample does that with islice.