# Python Identities of Sequence Slices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice, cpython

I have noticed something with the "identity", i.e., value returned by `id()`, of slices of certain sequence types that I simply can't wrap my head around.  I see it with lists and strings, which makes me think it is related to the implementation of either sequences or slices in CPython.

As covered in [3. Data model - Python 3.11.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> CPython implementation detail: For CPython, id(x) is the memory address where x is stored.

```py
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> l[3]
3
>>> l[7]
7
>>>
>>> id(l)
1931973192256
>>> id(l[3])
1931941276016
>>> id(l[7])
1931941276144
```

So far nothing unusual in that I expect to see different memory addresses for the list object than individual elements returned from the list.  However, the memory addresses don't make sense to me when looking at slices of the list:

```py
>>> l[2:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[3:9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> l[:-6]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> id(l[2:])
2813785568448
>>> id(l[5:])
2813784049664
>>> id(l[3:9])
2813784049664
>>> id(l[:-6])
2813784049664
>>> id(l[2:])
2813784049664
```

After the first slice of the list, `id()` is returning the same value regardless of what the slice looks like afterwards.

My question, what exactly is `id()` returning the memory address for when a list is sliced?  And a follow-up, why is the first and second slice identity different but slices after are the same, including the first slice?

Comment: You're creating new lists when slicing and throw them away immediately, as you don't keep any reference to them. Python is free to put your new list wherever it wants. The only thing guaranteed about ids is that they are unique *at one point in time*.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, are you saying that coincidentally Python/CPython is recycling the same address space over and over when subsequent sub-lists are generated by slices of the original list?

Comment: Python puts *any* object you create at any place it likes, and it can very well, or not, reuse the same address.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. After `id()` returns, the sub-lists are garbage collected, and the next sub-list uses the same memory.

Comment: You might see the same thing by entering `id([1])` followed by `id([2])`

Comment: @Barmar, I have never seen indexing (not slicing) return the same identity value when retrieving 2 different items from a list.  I am not saying it cannot happen, just that I have never seen it while it commonly happens with slicing.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because of the Cpython optimisation. Lets start from

```
>>> l[2:]
```

Slicing a [list always creates a new list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388247/6699447). Since allocating and deallocating a list object is an expensive operation, python interpreter keep track of [`free_list` which is an array of pointers to `PyListObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/internal/pycore_list.h#L26-L36).

```
/* Empty list reuse scheme to save calls to malloc and free */
#ifndef PyList_MAXFREELIST
#  define PyList_MAXFREELIST 80
#endif

struct _Py_list_state {
#if PyList_MAXFREELIST > 0
    PyListObject *free_list[PyList_MAXFREELIST];
    int numfree;
#endif
};
```

So when [you request for a new list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L155)(Remember slicing also create a new list) it's [served from this free list(if free list is available).](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L170-L174)

```
if (PyList_MAXFREELIST && state->numfree) {
        state->numfree--;
        op = state->free_list[state->numfree];
        OBJECT_STAT_INC(from_freelist);
        _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)op);
}
```

Since you are throwing away the list object immediately the python interpreter invokes [`list_dealloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L343) which will restore this `free_list`.

```
if (state->numfree < PyList_MAXFREELIST && PyList_CheckExact(op)) {
        state->free_list[state->numfree++] = op;
        OBJECT_STAT_INC(to_freelist);
}
```

When you do the slicing next time you are essentially getting reference to the same list object from `free_list`.